# Creating class of object in cycle

Tags: php, oop, object, memory, cycle

There was a need to create a class object in the cycle. The cycle can be 1000 or more iterations. I'm having doubts about the use of memory. Therefore, the question of whether to do so?. Ready to hear the pros and cons of using this design. In advance thank everyone for answers.

Code example:

```
foreach($entities as $entity) {
    $object = new $class($entity);
    $object->doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This wont affect memory. After each loop the new `$object` will fall out of scope and will be eligible for garbage collection. PHP is then free to remove the object from memory.

Answer (score 2):

Unless your class produce some trash in global space it won't affect (much) overall memory usage. Each instance will be disposed right at the end of cycle.